# store multiple images for one product

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on a basic e-commerce website using PHP/MYSQL on AWS. I just need to know how good approach to store multiple images with multiple size for a product.

The question is what is the best way to interconnect images in filesystem with product in DB:

I am thinking about:

keep the reference to unique folder dynamically created on amazon s3 for this product.

create new table in db (something like product_and_images) where we will keep information about product and images.

Thanks

Comment: Whenever multiple things come, means there will be two table.. 
One for 'Product Imformation'.. Another For 'Product Images..'
After submitting Product Details in 'Product' table.. get its ID.. and use this ID to store multiple images on 'ProductImages' table..

Comment: This ID is none other Product ID.. 
So, 'ProductImage' table will have 3 Column(mandatory) likely ImageNo (Primary Key, Auto-Incremented), ProductID(The ID which you got), ProductImage (where you will keep path of the image)

Comment: Thanks @DanishEnam Could use file system something like this /images/product_id/images

Comment: If you want more info, i can show one example of it

Comment: @DanishEnam Yes please.

Answer (score 0):

You may write paths of files in array and `serialize()` them. Then it could be written in DB.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hope I'm Able to understand your problem. Suppose, There are 2 tables. i.e. 'Product' table and 'ProductImages' table.

'Product' table having 3 column i.e ProductNo(Primary Key, Auto-Incremented), ProductName, ProductPrice
'ProductImages' having 3 column i.e ImageNo(Primary Key, Auto-Incremented), ProductNo, ProductImage
```

**Product-Information.php**

```
<form method='POST' action='Submit-Product-Information.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    Product Name: <input type='text' name='ProductName'>
    Product Price: <input type="text" name="ProductPrice">
    Product Image: <input type='file' name="ProductImage[]" multiple> //Since, Product Images are multiple.
</form>
```

**Submit-Product-Information.php**

```
<?
extract($_POST);

//First Insert Product Details
$sql = 'INSERT INTO Product(ProductName,ProductPrice)
       VALUES(:ProductName,:ProductPrice)';
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);  
$q->execute($task);

$ProductNo = $conn->lastInsertId(); //Get Product No

$TotalUploadedFiles=count($_FILES['ProductImage']['name']);

for($i=0;$i<$TotalUploadedFiles;$i++)
{
                $UploadedFileName=$_FILES['ProductImage']['name'][$i];
                if($UploadedFileName!='')
                {
                                $upload_directory = "Product Image/"; //Product Image Folder, Where you will upload Product Images
                                $TargetPath=time().$UploadedFileName;
                                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ProductImage']['tmp_name'][$i], $upload_directory.$TargetPath))
                                {    
                                    $sql = 'INSERT INTO ProductImages(ProductNo,ProductImage)
                           VALUES(:ProductNo,:TargetPath)';
                                    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);  
                                    $q->execute($task);                 
                                }
                }
}
?>
```

Comment: it is a good approach you use. but i have question about fetching one image against one product like. One product has many (4) images but i only want to show only one image against that product.

Comment: @AliRaza No problem for that too. Use `LIMIT 0,1` in your SQL Query. It will fetch only 1 image. `SELECT image_name FROM table_name <WHERE CONDITION> LIMIT 0,1`

Comment: sorry my question wasnt so clear, Want to show all the products in product table and also there images, but every product should show one image from image table. ( i use the inner join but inner join fetch all the image against one product, that is not what i want) if the question is not clear please do tell, ill try to explain further details. main thing is `All the products with only one image against each product`

Comment: Provide that query @AliRaza